# ADC ic's for SPI protocol

Tags: sensor, adc, spi, raspberry-pi, protocol

I want to know what are the ADC Ic's is suitable for SPI protocol? because i cant find MCP3008 ic in shops? No one having this IC.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search yourself ?  Typing into Google "ADC SPI" gives me some leads.

Comment: Why do people write "bcoz" ? It's such an eye sore.

Comment: @efox29 hi, i searched. but they suggesting MCP3008 ic. http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=49499

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JbLFU.png

Comment: @efox29 I can see some adc chips, most of them are having one input. MCP seems have 4/8 channel... Anyway thanks fox29 and others..

Comment: There are millions. Pick a manufacturer that you like and browse their site.

Comment: @efox29 because they are so lazy they even want us to do their googling for them.

Comment: @user25770 If you can't google, then instead walk into your local electronics shop and say "What SPI ADC chips with more than one channel do you have in stock?"

Answer (score 3):

(not a real answer, but too long for a comment)

user25770, look at your question. First you ask "I want to know what are the ADC Ic's is suitable for SPI protocol?" That question has a gazillion answers, and you even give one yourself: MCP3008. So clearly that is not what you want to ask.

Next you complain "because i cant find MCP3008 ic in shops?". OK, too bad for you. But which shops? Using http://www.findchips.com I see that this chip is available from all the big suppliers, and also from Microchip direct. So apparently you are referring to physical shops near to you. But how are we supposed to know which chips are available in shops near to you? Do did not even bother to tell use where you live!!!

(Even if you did tell us where you live the question would still be invalid for this forum as it would be a shopping question, but it would show at least the bare minimum effort from your side to formulate an question that could be answered.)